# Comparing entries in an array and removing duplicates (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, compare, duplicates

I have this little task I'm trying to accomplish in PHP/MySQL.

We're collecting fax-numbers (and other data) from customers that we'll use in case we have a problem with our operations at the company I work for (not in programming, don't worry).

Basically I have an array that looks something like this.

```
   Array
   [1]
      [company] => "Company A"
      [fax] => "031-558330"

   [2]
      [company] => "Company B"
      [fax] => "031558330"

   [3]
      [company] => "Company C"
      [fax] => "12345"
```

Note that [fax] is actually a duplicate in 1 and 2 if you remove the dash (-).

My problem is that I need to remove [2], because it's a duplicate of [1]. Basically, I'm trying to list unique fax numbers and print the company name of that unique fax number.

So far I've done this:

```
function format_text($text,$number)
{
    $text = str_ireplace(" ","",$text);
    $text = str_ireplace("-","",$text);
    $text = str_ireplace(",","",$text);
    $text = str_ireplace("/","",$text);
    $text = str_ireplace("+46","0",$text);
    $text = trim($text);

    return $text;
}


$fax_result = mysql_query("SELECT fax,company FROM beredskap GROUP BY company") or die(mysql_error());

for($i = 0; $fax_array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($fax_result); $i++) ;
array_pop($fax_array);

for($i = 0; $i<count($fax_array);$i++)
{ 
    $fn = format_text($fax_array[$i]['fax']);
    if(!empty($fn)) {
    echo trim($fax_array[$i]['company']) .",". $fn ."\n";

    }
}
```

I have no clue as to how I'm supposed to compare two subelements (as the raw data from the SQL might have differences in them, but when stripped of dashes and commas is duplicate to other entries), and then remove the parent key.

I sincerely hoped I've posed this question in the correct fashion.

Anyone willing to help out?
Thank you!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777160/comparing-array-in-php it might help full

Comment: in question there is a array matching algorithm by which you can also delete the matched element

Comment: Thanks Mayank!

eggyal (below) actually "nipped" this in the bud - before it ever entered PHP and became a problem, with his/her SQL-wizardry.

Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT   company,
         TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(fax,
           ' ',   '' ),
           '-',   '' ),
           ',',   '' ),
           '/',   '' ),
           '+46', '0')
         ) AS faxno
FROM     beredskap
GROUP BY faxno
```

Note that where the same fax number appears in the table against different companies, the above query will select one of those companies indeterminately.  If in such cases you would prefer to choose a particular company, please clarify how one determines the company that is to be selected.

Note also that this grouping will result in multiple entries in the resultset for a single company if that company has records with different fax numbers in the `beredskap` table, whereas your original query would have indeterminately chosen only one of such company's fax numbers.  If this is not your desired behaviour, please clarify how one determines the fax number that is to be selected.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I'm trying this one out.

If the same company appears twice - that's fine, because one company might have 5 different faces they want us to fax to in case of emergency.

I'm trying this one out and reporting back.

Comment: Are you.... are you a God?
This works EXACTLY as I was hoping.

I'm so envious of your logical wizardry.
Thank you so much.
Hopefully, others in my situation (and limited brainpower/experience) will see your elegant solution. Fix the problem before it enters PHP.